# possible casting issues with void pointer

Tags: c, casting

I have no clue as to what I am doing wrong with the below code..when compiled normally this is what error I recieve

> blob.c: In function ‘main’: 
>   blob.c:19:14: warning: dereferencing ‘void
>   *’ pointer [enabled by default] blob.c:19:14: error: request for member ‘x’ in something not a structure or union

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct {

int*x;

}TIM;


main(){
    void*o;

    TIM * a;
    a=(TIM*)malloc(sizeof(TIM));
    a->x=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *(a->x)=10;
    o=(void*)a; 
    free((TIM*)o->x);

    free((TIM*)o);
```

}

Could someone please point me in the right direction.Hints are welcome.WHole answers if hint seems too obvious.

Comment: Hint: `o->x` at line 19 is invalid because `o` at that point is not yet of type `TIM *` and therefore does not have a member `x`

Comment: [do not cast the return value of `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement

```
free((TIM*)o->x);
```

fails because `->` has higher precedence than the cast, since `o` is declared as `void*` the compiler doesn't know how to handle that.

Answer (score 2):

```
free((TIM*)o->x);
```

Should be

```
free(((TIM*)o)->x);
```